# Can't find dsym file for UUID from Crashlytics

Tags: uuid, crashlytics, google-fabric

Please help me in finding the issue where Crashlytics' is saying the the dSYM is missing for a given UUID. I have searched all of my dSYM file but the given UUID is not found. I have used this command: `mdfind "com_apple_xcode_dsym_uuids == <>"` to check the UUID from crashlytics.   There were 3 missing UUID Crashlytics reported. I have uploaded dSYMs for 2 of them, but struggling to find dSYM for last UUID.

Comment: Mike from Fabric here. Is this a local build, one sent to Testflight/Apple?

Comment: I have installed the build from iPA that has crahlytics installed in it. Sorry im new to iOS development.

Comment: Where did you get the .IPA from? Your machine or a build server?

Comment: I have got the ipa from my machine made an installable build link through i.diawi.com. Installed it on iOS device and in one of the instance app is crashing and Crashlytics is not tracking the issue

Comment: I'm not familiar with that site, do they do the build for you? If so, you'd need to find a way to look at the build server to get the dSYM

Comment: Actually what I did is after configuring the crashlytics, I have tested for the crash report through the debugging it directly to device. I get the the missing dsym in crashlytics dashboard I came to find the UUID there. I searched the dsym file for the given UUID but didn’t find the corresponding dsym file. Please help!!!

Comment: Ok, that's good info. If you look at Debug Information Format in your Xcode build settings - do you "Dwarf with dSYM" set for Debug builds and release builds? If not, set it for both and that will ensure dSYMs are created going forward.

Comment: Well i have double checked it its already selected and the Dsyms are getting created but the dysms that under my archive dont have matching uuid's that crashlytic has provided

Comment: In that case, I'm not sure what happened. We rely on the dSYMs created at build time to provide the symbolication information. I'd try a fresh build and see if the issue is reproduced or not.

Comment: even for me the crashlytics UUID is not available in my app DSYMs, can anyone help

Comment: Same issue here. Optional, did a search on the local machine with the UUID, and nowhere to be found.