# Can't find .dSYM for UUID from Firebase Crashlitycs

Tags: ios, firebase, flutter, crashlytics

Have a crash, tried to find it in Crashlitycs, see UUID in "Missing dSYMs". Tried to do all the things from [Firebase guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-deobfuscated-reports), but this command

```
mdfind -name .dSYM | while read -r line; do dwarfdump -u "$line"; done
```

don't show me UUID that I need. Tried to get dSYM file from the archives from XCode, it's not the same as in Crashlitycs. I already checked the GoogleService-Info.plist for GOOGLE_APP_ID. Where I can find the file that I need?

It looks simular to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44931719/cant-find-dsym-file-for-uuid-from-crashlytics) question, but there is no answer. Help me, please.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Ec1q.png) from Firebase console.

Answer (score 3):

Are you able to find these dSYMs if you go to the App Store under the app in question? Sometimes this is required, especially if you have bitcode enabled. You can try the `dwarfdump -u /path/to/dSYM` command on any dSYMs you want to upload to verify that the UUID matches one missing from your dashboard as well.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I didn't enable bitcode as I can see in Build Settings in XCode. Did you mean App Store Connect? I didn't release the app through the App Store or Testflight yet and I can't find dSYM files there.

Comment: Interesting...I think to debug this further you may want to reach out to Firebase support with your situation and what you've tried so far, and link to this post. Once we figure out what's going on I can update my answer here with next steps for anyone else who might be running into this. https://firebase.google.com/support/troubleshooter/contact

Comment: One more thing, did you try this from the SO post you linked? "If you look at Debug Information Format in your Xcode build settings - do you "Dwarf with dSYM" set for Debug builds and release builds?"

Comment: Yes, of course. For now, I use Sentry to see exceptions in release mode in iOS. Thanks for your help, I will try to contact support.

Comment: @KevinKokomani I am facing the same issue. By running the above command, I am unable to find my required uuid's dSYMs files. Is there a solution ?